# get each value in each key in order in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, items

I have a problem with getting values from dictionary.
For example, I have the dictionary:

```
dct={'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}
```

I want to get each value in each key in order.
Output should look like that:

```
1
4
7
2
5
8
3
6
9
```

Explanation:
1-first value in key 'a'
4-first value in key 'b'
7-first value in key 'c'
2-second value in key 'a'
5-second value in key 'b'
etc

Thank you in advance!!

I tried this version:

```
dct={'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}
    
for key, val in dct.items():
  for i in range(len(val)):
    print(val[i])
```

But it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean, didn't work?

Comment: The order of the for-loops is wrong. Of course you then have to find another way to retrieve `len(val)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
from itertools import chain

result = list(chain(*zip(*dct.values())))
```

Explanation: we collect values from the dict, zip them, producing something like `[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8)...]` and then flatten this list with `chain`